# C# - Masked text boxes's (how to get rid of the underscore in them)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How is it possible to get rid of the ugly underscore line in masked texboxe's in C# forms? Like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjiAF.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `PromptChar` property to something other than '_'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with the [PromptChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just a very simple numeric control you can always use [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) instead TextBox or MaskedTextBox (also you can hide it's arrows by simply setting `_numericUpDownControl.Controls[0].Hide();`). For more complex situations MaskedTextBox or a custom TextBox are appropriate.